# Whats the best practice for object pool pattern in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, object-pooling, flutter-state

Imagine a very simple application with two pages, *PostList* and *PostDetail*. On the former page, we show a list of *posts*, and on the latter, the details of a single *post*.

Now consider the following scenario. Our user clicks on the first *PostItem* and navigates to the *PostDetail* page. We fetch the full *post* data from the server. The **likes_count** of this *post* gets increased by one. Now if our user navigates back to the first page, the *PostItem* should be updated and show the new **likes_count** as well.

One possible solution to handle this is to create a pool of *posts*. Now when we fetch some new data from the server, instead of creating a new *post* object, we can update our corresponding pool instance object. For example, if we navigate to post with id=3, we can do something like this:

```
Post oldPost = PostPool.get(3)
oldPost.updateFromJson(servers_new_json_for_post_3)
```

Since the same object is used on the *PostDetail* page, our PostItem on the *PostList* page will be updated as well.

Other approaches that do not use a unique "**single instance**" of our Post objects, across the application, would not be clean to implement and requires tricks to keep the UI sync.

But the ObjectPool approach also has its own problems and leads to memory leaks since the size of the pool gets bigger and bigger over time. For this problem to get solved we need to **manually count the number of references** for each pool object instance and discard them when this count is equal to zero. This manual calculation is full of bugs and I was wondering if there are any better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Possibly a use case for [WeakReference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/WeakReference-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by using **streams** and `StreamBuilders`. First you create the **stream** and populates it with the initial data fetched from the API:
I like to use `BehaviorSubject` from `rxdart` but you can use normal streams too.

```
final BehaviorSubject<List<Post>> postsStream = BehaviorSubject<List<Post>>()..startWith(<Post>[]);
```

On the constructor body or `initState` function you would fetch the data and add it to the stream.

```
PostPage() {
  _fetchPosts().then((posts) => postsStream.add(posts));
}
```

You can now subscribe to changes on this `postsStream` in both pages with `StreamBuilder`. Any update you need to do you would emit a new (**updated**) `List<Post>` to the stream triggering a rebuild on any `StreamBuilder` subscribed to the stream with the new and updated values.

You can latter dispose the StreamController.

Comment: Hi Pedro, thank you so much for your thorough answer. Yeah, I'm familiar with this concept and I know that your approach will actually lead to a synced UI. But my question still remains. I want to have a single Post object (for each post_id) across the entire application. And of course, a way to solve the stated memory leaks problem.

Comment: Hi @EmadHedayati , sorry for not being able to help you more. I'm not familiar with this ObjectPool pattern, but it got me interested. Hope you find a more suitable solution soon and tell us.

Comment: No problem! Your answer was useful actually and I learned something new from it.